# how to combine and transfer objects to an array of a class w/ es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

it is necessary to write a class with methods for working on students. Let it be task 1. Next, I need to write another class that will contain objects from task 1 in the array.
as far as I understood, something like [{name: '' ...}, {name: ''}] should come out
But how to write it correctly, I just do not understand it or I am very stupid

Is it possible to create an array with objects right away or is this done by a method?

```js
class Student {
  constructor(fName, lName, birth, marks) {
    this.fName = fName;
    this.lName = lName;
    this.birth = birth;
    this.marks = marks;
    this.attendance = [];

  }
  midAttendance() {
    var count = 0;
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.attendance.length; i++) {
      if (this.attendance[i] === 'true') {
        count++;
        sum++;
      } else {
        sum++;
      }
    }
    return count / sum;
  }

  getAge() {
    return new Date().getFullYear() - this.birth;
  }
  midMark() {
    var count = 0;
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.marks.length; i++) {
      count++;
      sum += this.marks[i];
    }
    return (sum / count);
  }
  present() {
    if (this.attendance.length < 25) {
      this.attendance.push('true');
    } else {
      alert("full")
    };
  }
  absent() {
    if (this.attendance.length < 25) {
      this.attendance.push('false');
    } else {
      alert("full")
    };
  }
  summary() {
    var mMark = this.midMark();
    var mAttendance = this.midAttendance();
    if (mMark > 90 && mAttendance > 0.9) {
      return "molodec";
    } else if ((mMark > 90 && mAttendance <= 0.9) || (mMark <= 90 && mAttendance > 0.9)) {
      return "norm";
    } else {
      return "rediska";
    }
  }
}

class Students extends Student {
  constructor() {
    super(fName, lName, birth, marks);
  }
  let arr = [];
  getStudents() {

  }
}

let student1 = new Student('alex', 'petrov', '1999', [90, 94, 91, 91, 90]);
let student2 = new Student('vova', 'ivanov', '1994', [2, 3, 4, 3, 5]);
```

Comment: `Students` shouldn't be a subclass of `Student`. A collection of students isn't a student.

Answer (score 2):

`Students` shouldn't extend `Student`. `extends` is used to define a subclass, which represents an IS-A relationship. But a list of students is not a kind of student.

`Students` should be a completely independent class, e.g.

```
class Students {
    constructor() {
        this.arr = [];
    }
    addStudent(s) {
        this.arr.push(s);
    }
    removeStudent(s) {
        let index = this.arr.indexOf(s);
        if (index > -1) {
            this.arr.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
    getStudents() {
        return this.arr.slice(); // make a copy so they can't modify the actual array
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
let class = new Students;
class.addStudent(student1);
class.addStudent(student2);
console.log(class.getStudents());
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create an array of student objects and will give you the right output.

```
const students = [student1, student2]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, some tips for you!
Students should not extend the Student class. This kind of heritage has different purposes.
Also, I'd rewrite Student's methods to make its objective more clear.

If you want to return an array of objects of Students, I'd recommend you to loop/map though a list of students, and for each one of then return an formatted object that is pushed to an array.

On the Student class, you can also create a method that returns that formatted object, than just loop/map though the array of students executing the method and pushing the return into an array.